# How to export csv of variables for each object loop

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have been stuck on trying to export in the format needed for this script for a month now.  I can't figure out how to get it to export these variables in two separate loops into a single .csv file. We are given a .csv that contains `staging_input` and `staging_location` fields that both contain file locations on the network. We need to compare these two to make sure they are the same file count and size. I created a `ForEach-Object` loop for each of these fields and this gives me the desired output but I am unable to `export-csv` at the end of each loop into a single .csv.

[Desired final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoNQA.png)

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkOzN.png)

```
#User input CSV File and Workorder
$workorder =  Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the Fq job code'
   $pos = $workorder.IndexOf("_")
   $Client = $workorder.Substring(0, $pos)
   $Matter = $workorder.Substring(6, $pos)
   $job = $workorder.Substring($pos+7)

$csvoutputpath = "\\ldthost.pvt\client\" + $Client + "\" + $Matter + "\Proc\WKP\" + $job
$outputfilename = $workorder + ".csv"
$csvinputpath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input the directory of the CSV file containing Staging input and Staging location'

$staginginput = Import-Csv $csvinputpath | select -ExpandProperty staging_input 
$staginginputpath = $staginginput.TrimStart("\")
    #Get Child Item for each line
    $staginginputpath | ForEach-Object{
       # In here, we do whatever want to the 'cell' that's currently in the pipeline
       # Get File Counts
       $staginginputcount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$_ | Measure-Object).Count

       #Get size
       $staginginputsize = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$_ | Measure-Object -property length -sum
       $staginginputsize = $staginginputsize.sum / 1KB
   
   }

$staginglocation = Import-Csv $csvinputpath | select -ExpandProperty staging_location
$staginglocationpath = $staginglocation.TrimStart("\")
   #Get Child Item for each line
   $staginglocationpath | ForEach-Object{
      # In here, we do whatever want to the 'cell' that's currently in the pipeline
      # Get File Counts
      $staginglocationcount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$_ | Measure-Object).Count
      
      #Get size
      $staginglocationsize = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$_ | Measure-Object -property length -sum
      $staginglocationsize = $staginglocationsize.sum / 1KB
  }

  ##Export Final Output
  $data = @()
  $row = New-Object PSObject
  $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "staging_input" -Value $staginginput
  $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "staging_location" -Value $staginglocation
  $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "staging_input_File_Count" -Value $staginginputcount
  $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "staging_location_File_Count" -Value $staginglocationcount
  $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "staging_input_File_Size" -Value $staginginputsize
  $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "staging_location_File_Size" -Value $staginglocationsize
  $data += $row
  $Finaloutput = $csvoutputpath + "\" + $outputfilename
  $data | Export-Csv $Finaloutput -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Before digging into this. . .you just want to compare the 2 csv's? Does `Compare-Object` not give you the expected results?

Comment: Both `$staginginput` and `$staginglocation` are **arrays** of objects. Not single strings. Try `Compare-Object` as @AbrahamZinala suggested.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thanks so much for your response. Its more so comparing the size of directories inside the csv. There is only one csv that we are given that contains the directories that need the comparison. What we do is copy from staging input to the staging location so they should be the same but we need to check for quality assurance purposes. Would Compare-Object give the desired final output even if the import csv had lots of fields that need to be ignored?

Comment: That's up to you if the results fit your needs. Why not just run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single loop instead of two:

```
#User input CSV File and Workorder
$workorder = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the Fq job code'
$pos = $workorder.IndexOf("_")
$Client = $workorder.Substring(0, $pos)
$Matter = $workorder.Substring(6, $pos)
$job = $workorder.Substring($pos + 7)

$csvoutputpath = "\\ldthost.pvt\client\" + $Client + "\" + $Matter + "\Proc\WKP\" + $job
$outputfilename = $workorder + ".csv"
$csvinputpath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input the directory of the CSV file containing Staging input and Staging location'

$Finaloutput = $csvoutputpath + "\" + $outputfilename

Import-Csv $csvinputpath |ForEach-Object {
    # Calculate derived property values from `staging_input`
    $staginginputpath = $_.staging_input.TrimStart("\")
    $staginginputcount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$staginginputpath | Measure-Object).Count
    $staginginputsize = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$staginginputpath | Measure-Object -property length -sum
    $staginginputsize = $staginginputsize.sum / 1KB

    # Calculate derived property values from `staging_location`
    $staginglocationpath = $_.staging_location.TrimStart("\")
    $staginglocationcount = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$staginglocationpath | Measure-Object).Count
    $staginglocationsize = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\$staginglocationpath | Measure-Object -property length -sum
    $staginglocationsize = $staginglocationsize.sum / 1KB

    # output new object with the property values calculated above
    [pscustomobject]@{
        staging_input = $_.staging_input
        staging_location = $_.staging_location
        staging_input_File_Count = $staginginputcount
        staging_location_File_Count = $staginglocationcount
        staging_input_File_Size = $staginginputsize
        staging_location_File_Size = $staginglocationsize
    }
} | Export-Csv $Finaloutput -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed it to do.